# Arranging balls of two different colours in a straight line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I ran into the following problem while practising today: A collection of black and white balls are to be arranged on a straight line, such that each ball has at least one neighbour of different colour. If there are 100 black balls, then the maximum number of white balls that allows such an arrangement is?

So I decided to begin by first considering some smaller $n$ cases of $n$ black balls. Let white balls be denoted by $W$ and black ones by $B$. Since 100 is an even number, I decided to check from 2 and generalise for all even numbers.

Now, imagine two $B$, it is plainly observable that we can represent one possible sequence as $$WWBWWBWW.$$ Further probing leads me to believe that this in fact the case of maximised $W$. Observe that $W$=$2B+2$. Now whenever we add two $Bs$, it is easy to observe that $W$ will be maximum when we add the $Bs$ to the two extremes of an already existing sequence. Hence whenever we add two $Bs$, we add $Ws$. So the formula $$W=2B+2$$ holds for all even $B$. Hence for $B=100$, we get 202 white balls. But the textbook I am using lists the answer as 200. Is there some excess counting that I am doing here. Also is there a more elegant and concise approach? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that the two white balls at the ends of your example do not have a neighbouring black ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the two white balls at the ends of your example do not have a neighbouring black ball.

If you have $B$ black balls, there are $B - 1$ spaces between successive black balls in which you can place two white balls, with each white ball touching a black ball.  You can also place one white ball at each end.  Therefore, you can place at most $W = 2(B - 1) + 2$ white balls in the row of $B$ black balls so that each black ball has a white neighbour and each white ball has a black neighbour.  When $B = 100$, this yields $W = 2(100 - 1) + 2 = 2 \cdot 100 - 2 + 2 = 200$ white balls that can be placed in the row so that the conditions are met.

Comment: Aah, looks like I had forgotten to account for the colour condition being met at the extremes too.